# Get Neighbourhood maps with local ammenities based on current latitude and longitude

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

How to get neighborhoods and see if they're close to downtown, parks or other places of interest. How we can get  for nearby supermarkets, hardware stores, restaurants and other places for a given latitude and longitude.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Place searches</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: pyrmont,
  zoom: 15
});
```

var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
    };

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  var place = results[i];
  createMarker(results[i]);
  }
}
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 50%; float: left">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [TextSearchRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TextSearchRequest) method. It allows you to search for things like 'restaurants near sydney'.

Comment: but no map is displaying for me. Please tell me what extra code i have to add.I have posted my code. Please verify my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Give the map canvas a Height as well.